# is there any web interface / GUI to administer apache web server?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

is there any web interface / GUI to administer apache web server ?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you're seeking? There's Webmin/Virtualmin, Plesk, CPanel, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use webmin

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at webmin - www.webmin.com?

Answer (score 0):

[GAdminTools](http://gadmintools.flippedweb.com/) provides a C / GTK+ -based gui tools for Linux system administration, including Apache